# How "Scale for menu and title bars" works?

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

recently I bought new laptop which had 14" 1920x1080 screen. I would like to use multi monitor setup and I have 23" 1920x1080 screen at work and 22" 1680x1050 screen at home. I would like to use it at home and at work as well.
I am playing a bit with the setting.
Recently I found out the scale slider in Display setting in Ubuntu (Unity) works strange - you can set the scale factor for each display separately, but:

- you scale only menu and title bars -- who needs this? If I want to scale down or up I am interested in scale globally, otherwise I will have large menus and small application buttons, text, etc or vice versa. So what is this feature good for?
- second thing - I noticed when I upscale the display, not only menus and title bars are being scaled up, but also all fonts in the GUI is being scaled up. When downscaling, all other fonts except of the menu font, remains the same size. Is this as designed?

And the "question of the day": can I get reasonable setting to have comfortable size on both displays with different dpi?